# Try and finally in python

Tags: python, try-finally

```
def connect(self):
    ok = False
    try:
        conn = ftplib.FTP(self.hostname, self.user, self.password)
        ok = True
        return conn
    finally:
        if not ok:
            logging.error('Failed to connect to %s for %s' % (self.hostname, self.user))
```

I'm assuming it is not a good idea to return within the try block if there is something happening in the finally block.  I just want to be sure of the order of execution before I slam someones head!

Comment: It's kinda weird seeing how _exception_ is processed within the `finally` block (instead of the `except` one).

Comment: What's the question? It's not clear what you're actually trying to learn.

Comment: @raina77ow: Agreed. The only reason I can imagine ever wanting to do it this way is if I need to customize the exception chaining (in Python 3.2+).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm assuming it is not a good idea to return within the try block if there is something happening in the finally block.

You're assuming wrong. The whole point of a `finally` is that it *always* happens, even if you `return` or `break` early or raise an unhandled exception.* And it happens *after* the `return`.**

This is explained under [The try statement](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) in the documentation… but that isn't exactly the most novice-friendly section of the docs.

---

That being said, you seem to be using a `finally` block to fake an `except` block. Instead of having a flag that you check at `finally` time to see if there was an exception, just use the exception itself tell you that there was an exception:

```
def connect(self):
    try:
        conn = ftplib.FTP(self.hostname, self.user, self.password)
        return conn
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Failed to connect to %s for %s' % (self.hostname, self.user))
        raise
```

---

* That "always" is really only true within limits. If your program calls some C code that segfaults the interpreter, or you explicitly call `_exit`, or someone pulls the power cord in the middle of the program, the `finally` code obviously won't run.

** It might more precise to say it's happening in the middle of the `return`, but I think that just adds confusion; unless you're actually working on the guts of the interpreter, you can think of `return` as a single step.

Comment: That is what I wanted to know. I would even return outside of the try block once I know there was no exception. I find it that bit clearer to read.  I'm fed up finding junk like that floating around in here so heads will have to be slammed :-) Cheers

Comment: @nialloc: There's absolutely nothing wrong with `return` from the middle of a `try` block. People coming from languages like C often believe that you should only have a single `return`, at the end of a function—and that's a good rule for C (at least C89), but it's not a good rule for Python.

Comment: You misunderstand. I get multiple return blocks and I've used then.  In this example there is no need to do things this way.  Its slop pure and simple.  This is laziness, people just fudging in whatever they can to make things work without understanding what or why they are doing it.  The worst kind of developers :-)

Comment: @nialloc: The original example is certainly sloppy—trying to use a `finally` as an `except` is not exactly a sign of brilliant or diligent coding. But returning in the middle of the `try` is not sloppy. There's a distinction between the cases: if evaluating the `return` expression fails, should that be caught or not? If you understand what `try` does (which the coder you inherited from may not have, but you should), you'll be able to answer that, and then you put the `return` in whichever place does the right thing for that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rest assured the `finally` block is always executed.  The `return` in the `try` block doesn't change that.  No head slamming required ;-)

Comment: Well it should be try -> except -> return.  having to come back AFTER the return to check the finally flag is a disaster.  I just wanted to be absolutely sure the finally block would be executed.  Heads will be slammed :-)